# Since printf of a string works with an address in input, why printf does not accept just "argv"

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, printf, argv

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    printf("argv: %s\n",argv); // does not work and prints random stuff
    printf("*argv: %s\n",*argv); // works and prints ".a.out"

}
```

I test with:

```
./a.out nop
```

My confusion is this:

"argv" variable in the second line has the address of the first char of "./a.out".

"*argv" variable in third line is the first char of "./a.out".

So why `printf("argv: %s\n",argv);` to only print "./a.out" does not work?

I know that it's wrong, but I don't know why.

[image]

Comment: So, with`printf("%s", argv)`, you'd want to print `0x123` `0x456`?

Comment: `argv` is a pointer to the first element of an array of strings, it's not a string itself. `*argv` is exactly equal to `argv[0]` which is a string.

Comment: @pmg no I want to print "./a.out"

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude am I just passing a simple address (that is the same of the one of the first string char) to printf?

Comment: @Mat argv in the writing has inside 0x123, which is the address of the first char

Comment: Try printing the actual addresses themselves (e.g. `printf("argv = %p\nargv[0] = %p\n", argv, argv[0]);`) That should print two different values, because they are two different pointers.

Comment: You need to update your image, because `argv` isn't an array itself, it's a *pointer* to (the first element of) an array. So it's more like `argv -> argv[0]` and then `argv[0] -> "./a.out"`. Together it's `argv -> argv[0] -> "./a.out"`. You have two pointers, each pointing to different memory locations.

Answer (score 5):

`argv` is a pointer to a pointer. It means it "points" to addresses, not directly to characters.

So at address `argv`, other addresses are stored, not strings.
If you want to access the first string, you have to use the address of it, which is either `*argv` or `argv[0]`.

I don't know if it's clear enough, don't hesitate to ask for more clarifications.